# How to pass props to slot, Vue 3

Tags: vuejs3

Making a custom select box component. But having some trouble when I try to pass to slot.

```
<vb-select v-model="container"
           title="bla bla"
           multiple>
  <vb-option v-for="(item, idx) in items" :key="idx" :value="item">{{item}}</vb-option>
</vb-select>
```

`vb-option` is slot and I am calling it in `vb-select` component.

**vb-select**

```
<ul v-if="state" class="vb-options">
   <slot :state="state" :multiple="multiple"></slot>
</ul>
```

When I try to pass `multiple` to slot as a prop. I can't listen/watch it in the `vb-option`

**vb-option**

```
<li class="vb-option">
   {{multiple}}
</li>

props:{
  multiple:Boolean,
},
```

What is right way to achieve this? Watching props inside the slot for changes.

Answer (score 2):

```html
<slot :state="state" :multiple="multiple"></slot>
```

What you've done here is use [scoped slots](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-slots.html#scoped-slots) - but they don't quite work the way you're trying to use them.

Try this way:

```html
<vb-select>
  <template #default="scope"> <!-- you can also do #default="{ state, multiple }" -->
    <vb-option :multiple="scope.multiple" />
  </template>
</vb-select>
```

Slot scope isn't automatically applied to the props of the component you put inside the slot - you need to pass it explicitly as shown above.

So that's the "how slot scope works" part, but the second part is that you're trying to implement something called "compound components", and it's a little trickier than that in Vue. In React, to do this you'd use React Context, but in Vue you'd use provide/inject.

Here's a repo where I outline some usecases, including an select/option:
https://github.com/sethidden/vue-compound-components

If that's too crazy, there's really nothing wrong with doing something like this and handling option rendering in vb-select itself:

```html
<vb-select :options="[{ value: '123', label: 'Hello' }, { value: '567', label: 'Helloooo' }]" />
```

Comment: Your repo link is a 404.

Answer (score 0):

Pass hasError to default slot.

```
<script setup>
const slots = useSlots():
const Child = defineComponent({
  render: () => {
    const data = slots.default?.()[0];
    data!.props!.hasError = true;
    return data;
  },
});
</script>

<template>
  <Child />
</template>
```